# Why did my emails from a listserv stop threading?

Tags: gmail

I am part of a listserv that until late March, threaded messages from the same conversation. After late March, each reply to the same conversation comes in as a separate message. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

These emails likely don't include reference headers, or don't have the headers point to the previous message - these headers are now required. See [this blog post](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html) for more info.